# How to set account expiry date in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I wish to implement a new account policy in openldap that allow an administrator to set expiry date of user accounts. However, I can't find any related attribute in the object classes.

This is nothing related to password attributes like pwdMaxAge. The usage of this policy is for a subscription service. Once user has subscribed the server for a certain period, the administrator will set the account expiry date where subscription ends. User is authenticated if before expiry date and will fail to authenticated beyond the expiry date.

Is that possible to do so in openldap? I google and found that Microsoft's ActiveDirectory has AccountExpirationDate attribute.

Comment: You could use expiring objects for this.

Answer (score 7):

There's no direct support for account expiration in OpenLDAP or it's overlays (not even in `contrib/`).

Howard Chu [suggests](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200609/msg00021.html) using ppolicy's **pwdMaxAge** for this, which can be made to work, but I've found this less than ideal: If you're already using ppolicy for expiring passwords (in addition to expiring accounts), it will conflict with those settings and if you've configured grace logins (the sane thing to do), the user can change his password and thus reset the expiration timer.

So it seems the [best way](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200904/msg00077.html) to implement this (and a good way it is not) is by running an external task that sets the (ppolicy attribute) **pwdAccountLockedTime** to the magic number that indicates a manually locked account, which cannot be unlocked by the user.

> **pwdAccountLockedTime**
>
> This attribute contains the time that the user's account was locked. If the account has been locked, the password may no longer be  used  to authenticate the user to the directory.  If **pwdAccountLockedTime** is set to **000001010000Z**, the user's account has been  permanently  locked and may  only  be  unlocked  by an administrator. Note that account locking    only takes effect when the **pwdLockout** password policy attribute is  set       to "**TRUE**".

This external task (a cronjob, most likely) could be implemented in such a way that it reads the expiration date/time from a custom attribute (e.g. **expirationTime**) on the user record as it loops over them. That way you could store the expiration time/date on the user record, but of course the lockout relies entirely on this external task running.

Or you could write your own overlay.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Password Policy extension. It is supported from OpenLDAP 2.3 onwards. You may need to write some code to implement the required extended request/response controls.

If you're using OpenLDAP, you can use the dynamic objects overlay. Add `objectClass=dynamicObject` when creating the account, and set an appropriate `entryTTL` via the dynamic object refresh request.

Comment: Note that the DDS overlay documentation indicate that objects are deleted when they expire. If this seems too harsh in situations where you want the users to able to reactivate their account under certain conditions (e.g. they pay a bill). It is possible to add a *tolerance* time in DDS, during which the object are kept before deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shadowExpire` if the user account is of type [`shadowAccount`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ShadowAccount)

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenLDAP 2.5 you can use the [pwdEndTime](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-11.html#section-5.3.10) attribute from the ppolicy overlay to achieve account expiration:

Details from the [spec draft 11](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-11.html):

> This attribute specifies the time the entry's password becomes invalid for authentication. Authentication attempts made after this time will fail, regardless of expiration or grace settings. If this attribute does not exist, then this restriction does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

without getting to detailed - take a look at the PPolicy overlay mentioned above.  It works.  And you are correct, there is no "account expire time" like there is in AD.

One solution is to run a script that calculates the age of the account and add/modify the user attribute pwdPolicySubentry and set it to the DN of a policy that expires any password that is 1 second old and does not allow the user to change the password.

No client will get around that, and yet the user entry remains virtually intact.

Comment: No need for all that. Just set the `pwdAccountLockedTime` to the zero value specified in the password-policy draft.